# Will Request["Key"] will get the HTTP_HEADER variable also

Tags: c#, asp.net, httprequest

I am not getting wring answer for my question.

When I write

```
var name=Request["Key"]
```

I know that I can get values for `Get` or `Post`. 
Can I get the Request header values also like below?

```
var name=Request.Headers["Key"]
```

will be same as

```
var name=Request["Key"]
```

Or is there any difference.

### Edit 1

I have created a page and written this

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:54018/default.aspx");
request.Headers.Add("HTTP_USER", "shkehar");
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

and on default page If I write this

```
Request.Headers["HTTP_USER"]
```

I am getting the values

and when I say

```
Request["HTTP_USER"]
```

I am getting `null` value

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes you can.

Longer version:

`HttpRequest.Headers` is an instance of `System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection` and `NameValueCollection` has an `[]` operator, so you can get header values by typing:

```
var name = Request.Headers["Key"];
```

**EDIT:**

After original answer was edited, my answer should be: no you can't.

Documentation placed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.HttpRequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says: *To access data from the QueryString, Form, Cookies, or ServerVariables collections, you can write Request["key"]*.

So the statement:

```
var user = Request.Headers["HTTP_USER"];
```

is not an equivalent to:

```
var user = Request["HTTP_USER"];
```

Comment: So what will be the order will it look for Get, Post, or Header first?

Comment: I'm not really sure about the order but documentation placed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.HttpRequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) states: _To access data from the QueryString, Form, Cookies, or ServerVariables collections, you can write Request["key"]_. I don't know if order in this sentence is signifficant or not.

Comment: @शेखर: I edited my answer to address edit in your question